# Lookahead in regular expression

Tags: regex, r, regex-lookarounds

I am trying to use a regular expression in order to extract the part of a string before the first " / " occurrence. In the following example the initial string is "Atomic grouping / possessive qualifiers / conditional and recursive patterns" and i want to get "Atomic grouping"

```
library(stringr)
var.descr <- "Atomic grouping / possessive qualifiers / conditional and recursive patterns"
```

I tried the following but it matches the string until the `last` " / " occurrence (it returns "Atomic grouping / possessive qualifiers")

```
str_extract(var.descr, perl("^.+(?=\\s/)"))
```

Any help would be gratefully appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use lookahead regex like this:

```
str_extract(var.descr, perl("^.+?(?= / |$)"))
```

`(?= / |$)` will make sure either `/` is followed by the matched text or it matches till end of input.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/jF6fW9/3)

Comment: Thank you. Could you provide a modification in order to get the whole string when there is no " / " in it?

Comment: Thank you but I dont want to exclude "/", only " / ". For example if there is an "and/or" in the string (before the first " / ") I don't want it to be excluded

Answer (score 1):

You can use the "lazy" `+` with `?` after it

```
str_extract(var.descr, perl("^[^/]+"))
```

Comment: Thank you. Could you provide a modification in order to get the whole string when there is no " / " in it?

Comment: Thank you but I dont want to exclude "/", only " / ". For example if there is an "and/or" in the string (before the first  " / ") I don't want it to be excluded